# Is this nonparametric tests with the same data valid?

Tags: nonparametric, experiment-design

I have 6 algorithms, and each algorithm I use on N problem instances (say N is around 200).
I divided the algos into two groups, 3 into group A and 3 into group B. They are divided into two groups based on a characteristic of the algos. So that we can actually say that I have 3 variants of algo A, and 3 variants of algo B.  In each group I will do multiple comparison using Friedmand test + post hoc to show that there are significant differences in performance among algos in each group.
Afterward, using simple comparison, I get the best performing method in A, and the best performing method in B. Say the two methods are called Ax and Bx. Now I want to compare Ax and Bx, and use wilcoxon signed test to find out that if Ax is better than Bx (or vice versa, or not better). Is this series of comparison valid?  Will there be a problem because I use the same data repeatedly on two different comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you select Ax and Bx based on all N instances taken together, rather than using the best performing A and B for each instance separately. What you do violates independence between instances (as assumed by the test), so one can argue that it is invalid.

That said, I tend to argue that the idea is wrong that model assumptions need to be literally fulfilled for statistical inference to be valid, because nothing in life is really perfectly independent of anything else, and if we insist in model assumptions to be perfectly fulfilled, we can't ever do anything. The really relevant issue is always *whether model assumptions are violated in a way that would with too large probability mislead conclusions from the inference*. This in general depends on what exactly is done and how conclusions are to be interpreted.

As a first reaction I was thinking that maybe violations of independence are not critical here, but thinking a bit more about it, I now think they could be. Consider a situation in which A1, B1, B2 and B3 are equally good, and much better than A2 and A3. This means that A1 will win the A-competition easily, whereas there will be a random winner in the B-competition. The winner in the B-competition can be expected to have performed better on the given instances than it should be on average, because it was selected against equally good alternatives. Therefore it will have an advantage against A1 which could just win the A-competition on a normal performance. So no, this is invalid. It may be possible to devise a resampling/permutation scheme that could test Ax against Bx in a valid manner based on the Wilcoxon (or any other) test statistic, but for the moment I'm too lazy trying to design it.

Comment: what if I already found that A1 and B1 is equally good? I found this by firstly do a multiple comparison on the 6 algos altogether. And this shows in the A-competition and B-competition, A1 and B1 are better than their corresponding variants, and have significant difference.

Comment: @Sanyou I don't really understand how you could "find that A1 and B1 is equally good". Later you say they have significant difference, which contradicts what you wrote first. Also I don't understand how what you write improves the situation in comparison to the situation I outlined.

Comment: @Sanyou Generally, the more you use information based on the earlier comparison involving all data, the stronger will the later independence assumption be violated. So arguing that "looking at the earlier information you already know that XXX" will most likely not help.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, and forgive my (really) lack of common sense on this. I have gut feelings that what I wrote will probably worsen my predicament.  What if I only do multiple comparison once on the 6 algorithms, and found out that A1 and B1's difference is not significant, is that the end of it? or is there anything I need to do to further find out whether they really are (not) significantly different?

Comment: On the other hand, I actually need that A-competition and B-competition, because A1 and B1 are the results of modification of the algorithm on a higher level that I proposed, therefore I need to also prove that the modification I propose improve the algorithm significantly

Comment: @ChristianHennig great seeing you in person and hearing your great talk at the Joint Statistical Meetings in Toronto.  One additional thought: instead of doing sub-tests I'd try to embed the entire analysis into one statistical model for inference.  Example parametric and non-parametric paired-data models are given [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar.html#sec-nonpar-pairmodel).

Comment: @Sanyou Could you test the A-winner against the B-winner on new data? (What Frank Harrell wrote is also worth looking into.)

Comment: @Sanyou Also you need to have in mind generally that you cannot know not observing significance that two treatments are equal. A significance test addresses whether *equality is compatible with the data*, but data may be too weak to find a difference even if it exists. (It may occasionally also be so strong to find a difference that is so small that it is actually irrelevant.) Whether one analysis is "the end of it" really depends on how precisely you want to know, and how much additional effort (new data) you are prepared to invest.

Comment: @ChristianHennig  Sorry, I have a hard time understanding your first sentence of your last comment. It's actually hard to do with new instances, because the instances come from a specific paper. On the other hand, there is no restriction to use my own generated instances, so that I can do A-competition, B-competition, and Ax vs Bx, all with different instances, but I still need to use those instances from that paper, because it's kind of important to show that my algorithms works well (and better than other algos) on those instances.

Comment: @Sanyou I was saying that an insignificant result in general means that a test is inconclusive, and not that the null hypothesis is true. Re the other question, you could randomly distribute instances into two parts, run A- and B-competition on one part and run Ax vs. Bx on another. This of course reduces the sample size for them both, and more efficient procedures may be possible but may require some time to devise.

Comment: Thank you, I think redistributing the instances into the two competition is the most feasible option. One last question if I may, after I got the winner, say C. Can I use all of the instances from the paper to test algo C vs new algorithms (say algorithms from group D)?

Comment: @Sanyou: No. Because once more the fact that C was winner in some competition based on (partly) the same data makes it more likely that C performs somewhat better on these data than it would in general. (Although also note that you can compare everything with everything else based on average performance if you don't run hypothesis tests and make significance statements.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm starting to understand the underlying logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147867/discussion-between-sanyou-and-christian-hennig).